# Does the Database Design of my program have a circular reference issue?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, doctrine-orm

[image: the design]

So Basically

```
One User (Uploader) -> has 'many' Contents 
One Content -> has many Comments 
One Comment -> has one User
```

From the DB design it looks like circular reference?

Comment: Is the `user_id` column necessary in the `Comment` table? Can't the user be identified via the `Content` table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that what is being modelled here is a situation where a person can post an initial piece of content, and then that same user *or other users* can post comments - something along the lines of StackOverflow, Facebook, an online forum, etc.

If that is the case then I don't see any problem at all. The two users have different meanings, they are playing different roles - you need both in order to know who made the initial post, and who made each comment that is attached to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, no, and this would be more clear to you if you express the relationships only in terms of which one is the "parent"

```
One User    -> has many Contents 
One Content -> has many Comments 
One User    -> has many Comments
```

This is a correct representation of the data model, and does not lead to a situation in which A is the parent of B, which is the parent of C, which is the parent of A.

Comment: Good point, here; it's made me think that this is a situation where using an E-R or similar diagram with named roles between the entities could be helpful. i.e. A model showing something like this: User [creates] Content, Content [is replied to by] Comment, and User [posts] Comment. When think about what the entities are *doing* to create the data, it's more obvious that there's no conflict here than when just looking at a database structure.

Comment: Well, maybe -- it ought to be clear from the E-R diagram without named associations between the tables.